# Spark 2.3.1 array_join and array_remove

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, downgrade

I have coded a pyspark script to execute a SQL file, it worked perfectly fine on the spark latest version, but the target machine has 2.3.1, and it throws exception:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Undefined function: 'array_remove'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'
```

It seems these are not present in the older versions :( can anyone suggest something, i have searched alot but in vain.

my sql piece which is failing is

```
SELECT NIEDC.*, array_join(array_remove(split(groupedNIEDC.appearedIn,'-'), StudyCode),'-') AS subjects_assigned_to_other_studies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_remove](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_remove) and [array_join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_join) functions were added on spark version 2.4. You can make an UDF and register it to use in a query using [this method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration.register).

Comment: if i create such function, will have to code it using python?

Comment: @shzyincu yes, then, you can register this function and use inside your sql file.

Comment: Your link to the method is out of date.  New link for 2.3.1:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration.register